# Increase randomness of deep learning output by keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have `simpleRNN` style model

```
    n_hidden = 512
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(n_hidden, input_shape=(12, 4), return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(n_hidden, activation="linear")) 
    model.add(Dense(4, activation="linear"))
    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
    model.summary()
```

OK it works for text deep learning.

Now I give first words and make sentence.

However if I give the same word. model always giving back same sentence.

For example, learn these sentences

- I have a pen.
- I have cars.
- I punch the tree.

Giving `I` as first sentence, it always return `I have ..`

However ,I want to get `I punch ..` sometimes.

I guess I think I should introduce some randomness.

Is it correct? and how can I do that??

---

For now, my prediction.

Each item is an array consists of 12 number.

I use 4 items to predict next an array.

Current my source code.

```
in_ = basicdata[0].x[:1]
# in_.shape =  (1,4,12)

predicted = []
NUM_DATA = 100
cnt = 0
for i in range(NUM_DATA):
    out_ = model.predict(in_)  # somehow get multiple output here??
    #it returns only 1 answer.
    #out_.shape = (1, 12) 


    in_ = np.concatenate((in_.reshape(12, 4)[1:], out_), axis=0).reshape(1, 12,4) 
    if cnt == 0:
        predicted = out_
    else:
        predicted = np.concatenate([predicted,out_],axis=0)
    cnt = cnt + 1
```

I put (1,4,12) in model and get (1,12)

I guess I should get not `(1,12)` but `(2 or more,12)` and then use `tf.random`

However Where should I change??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *sample* from the output probabilities rather than taking the highest probability (argmax). There is a Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) which covers that.

> Note: It is important to sample from this distribution as taking the argmax of the distribution can easily get the model stuck in a loop.

> To get actual predictions from the model you need to sample from the output distribution, to get actual character indices. This distribution is defined by the logits over the character vocabulary.

This is *roughly* how you can do it:

```
predictions = model(X_test)
sampled = tf.random.categorical(predictions[0], num_samples=1)
sampled = tf.squeeze(sampled, axis=-1).numpy()
```

```
array([41])
```

Comment: Thank you very much you give me the clear outline. However i still have some questino my `model()` or `model.predict()`  returns only 1 answer. I need re-build the model and where should I change?? I guess I should change my model from `argmax` to another though ...

Comment: Calling the model, i.e. `model(X)` will output a tensor with the size of the posible categories. So it wouldn't only output one answer.

Comment: `model(X)` returns (1,12) so it's not one array as you told. but I want to get multiple array like (10,12),where can I set the output number??

Comment: You need to set `return_sequences=True` to return sequences. But that's not directly related to your question. Be careful though, if you return sequences, your output will also need to be a sequence! My solution will (more or less randomly) select from your 12 categories (e.g., punch, have, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much @Nicolas. I still struggle with `return_sequences=True` and maybe don't understand correctly, but your answer gives me a progress. For no accepted as answer.